# How to logout of tf.exe and login through another account with 2FA enabled?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to delete a workspace from one PC and it keeps telling me that the user does not have permission for whatever. I want to logout from tf.exe and login through an administrator that has 2FA enabled.

I'm stuck at this point. Removing everything from Windows Credentials did not work. Also restarting Windows did not work.

It's possible to use `/login:username,password` option, but the Administrator account has 2FA enabled, and also the `password` part is typed in cleartext which is a major security breach in real scenarios.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
TF.exe settings connections
```

Then you will get the server URL and the connected user:
[image]

Then you should type the following command with your server URL:

```
TF.exe settings connections /switchuser [SERVER URL]
```

Next time you will run a TF command a popup will rise asking for credentials.